# Assembly x86: How to display image that converted to zeros and ones?

Tags: image, assembly, x86

I made an example image. I want to display it on startup of my OS. I made a Python program to convert my image's pixels to zeros and ones. Black equals `0` and white equals `1`. I switched places because the background of the OS is black. How can I loop my image's pixels to display on screen? I use `int 10h / ah=0h` to set display mode. I use `13h` (320x200) mode. The position of the displayed image can be anything. Any part of the image won't be outside of the screen.

Example code:

```
; Pixels that converted to zeros and ones: (00 byte tells that row ends.)
pixels: db '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 0
        db '0111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 0
        db '0111111000000011111000111110000000000110000001000100010', 0
        db '0110000001100111111001111110001111000110000000100100100', 0
        db '0110000001100110000001100000011111100110000000010101000', 0
        db '0111111000000110000001100000011001100110000000000000000', 0
        db '0111111001100111111001111110011111100110000001110101110', 0
        db '0110000001100111111001111110011000000110000000000000000', 0
        db '0110000001100110000001100000011001100110000000010101000', 0
        db '0111111001100110000001100000011111100111100000100100100', 0
        db '0111111001100110000001100000001111000111100001000100010', 0
        db '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 0

; Setting display mode:
mov ah, 0   ; set display mode
mov al, 13h ; set 320x200 pixels
int 10h     ; set it

; I use these lines to put pixel:
mov cx, 10  ; col
mov dx, 10  ; row
mov ah, 0ch ; put pixel
```

Comment: _"t needs to be displayed full on screen"_ It's not clear what you means by that? From what I can tell, your image is 55x12 "pixels". 320 is not an integer multiple of 55 - same for 200 and 12. Were you planning on doing some kind of interpolation when upscaling it? In any case, I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. You just need to loop over the image array and plot pixels as you go along.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I thought looping over the image too. I am writing the code. If it works, i will post it.

Comment: @Michael, I wrote the code. It worked but it is small. You are correct. "*I made an example image.*", this was example. I will make an image with size `320x200`.

Comment: Anti-compressing your image to 1 bit per byte is the opposite of what you normally want.  Now your 55x12 image takes 660 bytes + 12 bytes of padding instead of 83 bytes, so your program can't fit in a 512-byte bootloader, for example.  Looping over the bits of an integer is pretty easy with `shr` to shift a bit into CF, then `adc reg,0` to get that bit into another register.

Comment: I made a second sector for my bootloader. Yes, the size is problem but I found a new way. Maybe the size will be about 8 times smaller. Example, the bytes are in `00 01 00 02` format but we can do this in bits. 1 byte is 8 bytes so we can work on bits. If we convert our example byte into this, the byte will be `0x010`. We can not tell the row end because we work on binary (2 cases) but we need 3 cases (`0, 1, 2`). So we will use 1 byte to specify the row length. If you did not understand something, tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that I can loop this to draw an image. It skips the black pixels and draws the white pixels. If you want to make it draw pixels bigger, you can increase `cx` and `dx` by `2`.

Code:

```
mov ah, 0
mov al, 13h
int 10h

mov si, pixels
mov cx, 10
mov dx, 10
mov ah, 0ch

drawloop: ; Loop
lodsb ; Set al the memory address of si and increase si
cmp al, 0 ; Is the pixel black?
je drew
cmp al, 2 ; Did the row end?
je rowend
cmp al, 3 ; Did the image end?
je finish
int 10h ; Draw a pixel

drew: ; If the pixel was black, increase cx
inc cx
jmp drawloop

rowend: ; If row ended, increase dx and reset cx
inc dx
mov cx, 10
jmp drawloop

finish:

jmp $ ; Infinite loop

pixels: db 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 2
        db 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 2
        db 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0, 2
        db 0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0, 2
        db 0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0, 2
        db 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 2
        db 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0, 2
        db 0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 2
        db 0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0, 2
        db 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0, 2
        db 0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0, 2
        db 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 3
```